# Loan Application in South Dakota

Tags: united-states, mortgage, home-ownership, home-loan

A co-worker of mine is going in to apply for a loan and start the closing documents for their home, and from the sounds of it they are not going through a Realtor because they are already living in the home and a portion of the rent is going towards the down payment.

They want to know stuff like how much does an Appraiser cost and what they will need to prepare for the loan application process.

Preferably specific to South Dakota if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

South Dakota does not require a realtor or a real estate attorney according to [this state by state guide](http://www.escrowhelp.com/state-by-state-closing-guide.html).  The lender or title company is permitted to perform the closing.  He may want to consider getting a real estate attorney if he's not completely comfortable with the whole process; their fee will be less than a realtor's normal 3%, usually a few hundred dollars (at least in Illinois, where it's sort of a loss leader for getting other kinds of business).  That might be worth it to have someone knowledgeable on his side.  He also might be able to find a realtor who will act as his agent in this process for a lower, fixed fee, since he's not doing the normally more difficult part of the job (finding the house!).

Price for appraisers will vary, and isn't really something on topic for this site in specifics.  Generally speaking, appraisals run between a few hundred and a thousand dollars depending on the complexity of the property; I don't see why South Dakota would really be different.

His lender should be able to explain all of the things he needs from them, but at minimum, he probably needs a few years' tax returns including W2s, bank statements, a pen with a lot of ink for signing things.  He'll need an appraisal for the lender, and he'll need someone - whether it's an attorney, a realtor, a title company, or whatnot - to verify the title is clear of encumbrances (usually a title company does this where I'm from, but SD may be different).

He probably doesn't need a home inspection since he lives there already, but if he's not very knowledgeable about home repair he may want to get one anyway: you find out things like the roof needs replacing soon, the foundation has some potential leaks, and other things that he may not be able to tell on his own.  (Watch "Holmes Inspection" or similar shows to see what an inspector might find, in a worst case scenario.)  He should, however, have a good idea of home repair costs, and make sure he either has money for them or considers a loan that includes these repairs in it.

He needs home insurance; he may already have rental insurance, in which case he might use the same provider.  The lender may offer to get insurance for you, but don't take theirs - it's probably very expensive.  He needs to actually pay the premium before the closing, at least in IL, and bring evidence of this payment to the closing (but don't pay before the mortgage is fully cleared unless the insurance payment is refundable if it falls through!).  Some people pay their insurance premium at closing from what I've heard, but we did it a day ahead of time to be sure it went through properly.

He'll also probably need a certified check for the closing costs, and possibly more than one if another party (like a title agent) is present.  This should be something the lender will clarify.

He'll want to allow a month or so for all of this.  Not having moving time or cost helps.

He should also probably look at a few help pages on 'what to do at closing', such as [here](http://www.homeloanlearningcenter.com/Howdoyou/Step6Closing.htm).